# How can i not get the list index out of range error from this code?

Tags: python, list

Im downloading the followers from 2 twitter accounts and putting them into a list of dictionaries. I downloaded 10 followers from account1 and 10 followers from account2. And with the following code i take the first 4 followers of account 1 and the first 4 of account2 and display them

```
twitter_accounts = ["account1", "account2"]
res = {}
follower = []
pbar = tqdm_notebook(total=len(twitter_accounts))

for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:
    inner_structure = []
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=twitter_account,
                              skip_status=True, include_user_entities=False).items(10):
        val = page._json
        inner_dict = {}
        inner_dict["name"] = val["name"] 
        inner_dict["screen_name"] = val["screen_name"]
        if inner_dict not in inner_structure:
            inner_structure.append(inner_dict)

    res[twitter_account] = inner_structure
    pbar.update(1)

pbar.close()

for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:  
        for i in range(4):
            display(res[twitter_account][i]['screen_name'])
```

So the final result will be the displaying of the first 4 followers of acc1 and the first 4 of acc2.

But what i really need to do is take those 8 strings and instead of displaying them storing them into an array.

I tried this way but i get an index out of range error.

```
for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(8):
            follower[j]= res[twitter_account][i]['screen_name']
```

How can i store them in an array without getting the error?

Comment: Try with this list comprehension: `followers = [res[twitter_account][i]['screen_name'] for i in range(4) for twitter_account in twitter_accounts]`.

Comment: Wouldn't `print(followers)` work? Or if you want them one by one `for follower in followers: display(follower)`.

Comment: @Guimoute by doing so it only takes 1 string not all 8.

Comment: the first one returned me only 1 follower name which makes me think that it has stored only 1. The second one returned me the same name 8 times in a row. And i even tried for i in range(8) followers[i] but the result was the first 8 letters of the follower name

Comment: The problem is that `follower` is an empty list and `follower[j]` is out of range.

Comment: And that's interesting. Can you make sure that when you access a single follower it's indeed a string (the full name)?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i know i thought of that too but i dont really know how to insert values in an empty list if it gives me this problem

Comment: @Guimoute i didnt  really get the question sorry

Comment: @Guimoute I treid your first example and it worked thank you

Comment: @Guimoute When I don't know what operations available, I go to google. For example, here you can google "python list" to find general information about python lists or "python add elements to list" to find something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either declare the list first, and append elements to it:

```
followers = []
for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:
        for i in range(4):
            followers.append(res[twitter_account][i]['screen_name'])
```

Or use a list comprehension directly (which I believe works but I can't test right now):

```
followers = [res[twitter_account][i]['screen_name'] for i in range(4) for twitter_account in twitter_accounts]
```

Whichever you find clearer and more readable (-:

Comment: im trying the first one now and and see if it works

Comment: I suggest changing `for i in range(4):` to `for user in res[twitter_account]:` and then you can do `user['screen_name']`.